# Web project not Running on Browser (error 500)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jstl, jparepository

I am learing spring boot and am On a project named DocumentWeb it is a simple web project with a controller, a jsp the mode and the Document Repository (interface) which extends the JpaRepository

The project should enable a user to upload a pic and also download any pic that has been uploaded and save it to the database as blob.But not running on the browser .
When ever i coment out the implementation of the document reposiry in the controller it runs finelly. but no error in the code.Please Help

This is my code:

```
//Controller
package com.javaMadeEasy.document.controllers;

import com.javaMadeEasy.document.entities.Document;
import com.javaMadeEasy.document.repository.DocumentRepository;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class DocumentController {
    @Autowired
    DocumentRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/displayUpload")
    public String displayUpload(ModelMap modelMap){
        extracted(modelMap);
        return "DocumentUpload";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadDocument(@RequestParam("document") MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestParam("id") Long id, ModelMap modelMap){
//       multipartFile.getName();
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setId(id);
        document.setName(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            document.setData(multipartFile.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        repository.save(document);

        extracted(modelMap);
        return "DocumentUpload";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/download")
    public StreamingResponseBody download(@RequestParam("id") long id, HttpServletResponse response){
        Document document =repository.getOne(id);
        byte[] data  = document.getData();

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=download.jpeg");

        return outputStream -> {
            outputStream.write(data);
        };
    }


    private void extracted(ModelMap modelMap) {
        List<Document> documents = repository.findAll();
        System.out.println(documents.size());
        modelMap.addAttribute("documents",documents);
    }
}
```

```
//Model
package com.javaMadeEasy.document.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Lob;

@Entity
public class Document {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
//Repository
package com.javaMadeEasy.document.repository;

import com.javaMadeEasy.document.entities.Document;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document,Long> {
}
```

```
//application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb
spring.datasource.username=devuser
spring.datasource.password=Mamzy123

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/documentWeb

logging.level.sql=debug
logging.level.web=debug
#logging.level.root=debug
```

```
//DocumentUpload.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document Upload</title>
</head>
<h3>Upload A Photo</h3>
<body>

<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <pre>
        Id:<input type="text" name="id"/>
        Document:<input type="file" name="id"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        <input type="reset" value="refresh"/>
    </pre>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>link</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${documents}" var="document">
        <tr>
            <td>${document.id}</td>
            <td>${document.name}</td>
            <td><a href="download?id=${document.id}">download</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

```
//pom.xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javaMadeEasy.document</groupId>
    <artifactId>documentWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>documentWeb</name>
    <description>Vendor Module</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating your DocumentRepository interface with `@Repository`?

Answer (score 0):

use @Repository annotation in a Repository java interface.

And to check the server logs. The logs may provide more detailed information about the error, such as the specific line of code that is causing the issue.